# Ifconfig and IPtables Configuration

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, ubuntu-14.04, ifconfig

Would someone explain this below output of ifconfig command. This PC is using USB IP4 Internet connection.

For example: why there is, inet6 addr: fe80::5a2c:80ff:fe13:9263/64 Scope:Link, assigned /

active on eth1, and why loopback is active.

Am trying to configure IPtables with minimum connections as possible and minimize the risk of intrusion.

I did not find an answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466502/different-output-between-network-tool-3-8-1-and-terminal-traceroute).

With many updates and upgrades to Ubuntu since 12.04.

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------/

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:33:c6:64:94

```
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0

      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0

      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 

      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 58:2c:80:13:92:63

```
      inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

      inet6 addr: fe80::5a2c:80ff:fe13:9263/64 Scope:Link

      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

      RX packets:5291 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0

      TX packets:4188 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0

      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 

      RX bytes:4658548 (4.6 MB)  TX bytes:458475 (458.4 KB)
```

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback

```
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0

      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host

      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1

      RX packets:783 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0

      TX packets:783 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0

      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 

      RX bytes:75702 (75.7 KB)  TX bytes:75702 (75.7 KB)
```

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------/

This commend return empty results: nmcli dev list iface eth0 | grep IP4

----------------------------------------------------------------------------/

This commend : nmcli dev list iface eth1 | grep IP4

returns,

IP4.ADDRESS[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466502/different-output-between-network-tool-3-8-1-and-terminal-traceroute):                         ip = 192.168.1.100/24, gw = 192.168.1.1

IP4.DNS[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466502/different-output-between-network-tool-3-8-1-and-terminal-traceroute):                             192.168.1.1

IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.8.8

------------------------------------------------------------------------------/

Uname -a: 3.13.0-35-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 15 01:58:42 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64

x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

In the folder /etc/network you have the interfaces file, in which you can configure your Ethernet configuration. With something like this:

```
#Configure Loopback
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
#The primary network interfaces
auto eth0
iface eth0 intet static
address X.X.X.X
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway X.X.X.255
```

I hope this can help